# Dynamic Store Dir with CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, carrierwave

Only new to Rails but I've started been using CarrierWave for my upload handling. I am trying to make a media hosting app whereby:

- A Show belongs to a User
- A Show has many Episodes
- An episode belongs to video

At the moment I am using single table inheritance to store my video content into a meta data type Asset table, all is saving well. The issue I'm trying to get to is when I save the video via CarrierWave I want to be able to get both the show slug and the episode slug into the save path.

Currently I have this set up with my shows and episode uploads:

```
def store_dir
  "shows/#{model.friendly_id}/cover/"
end
```

And previously before STI i would just store the filename in a video field in the episodes table and have it store via:

```
def store_dir
  "shows/#{model.show.slug}/episodes/#{model.id} - #{model.friendly_id}"
end
```

Only problem now I cannot get the episode information from my video model in the CW uploader.

My models are:

Show.rb

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base

  #Associations
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :episodes

  #Slugs
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  #Carrierwave
  mount_uploader :image, ShowImageUploader

end
```

Episode.rb

```
class Episode < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :show
  belongs_to :image, :class_name => "Episode::Image"
  belongs_to :audio, :class_name => "Episode::Audio"
  belongs_to :video, :class_name => "Episode::Video"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :video, :image, :audio

  before_save :add_guid, :on => :create

  #Slugs
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  validates :title, :presence => true, :length => {:within => 5..40}

  protected

  def add_guid
    self.guid = UUIDTools::UUID.random_create.to_s
  end

end
```

episode/video.rb

```
class Episode::Video < Asset

  mount_uploader :video, EpisodeVideoUploader, :mount_on => :filename

end
```

asset.rb

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

So I guess how can I get the appropriate data after upload into:

```
"shows/#{model.show.slug}/episodes/#{model.id} - #{model.friendly_id}"
```

Thanks!